# How to detect a particular icons in an image which is rotation variant?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In the below input image I need to detect the aircrafts using openCV in python. The biggest challenge here is the aircrafts to be detected are rotation variant which means they can be rotated in any direction. But still the algorithm needs to detect as shown below. I tried with template matching but it was able to detect only the aircraft that is exact match of the template.If aircraft is rotated in any other direction it wasn't able to detect.I am newbie to image processing so any ideas/thought will be very much helpful.

[image: Input Image :]

[image: Expected Output :]

Answer (score 1):

I dont sure if it will work for general case but for your picture it is very easy

```
    img=cv2.imread('air.jpg')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _,mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    rect=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
    dilation = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel=rect, iterations=1)
    contours = cv2.findContours(dilation,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
    for cont in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please check on that ?

Comment: see my answer, I have no much time, just read my code

Comment: In some scenarios there will be no square boxes. Only flight icon on a green background. So I am looking for a generalized solution.

Comment: For another picture make new question